# Не могу изменить активный класс ссылки в navbar bootstrap 4 с помощью jquery

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap, sass

Мне нужно изменить активный класс ссылки после нажатия на неё в navbar bootstrap 4 с помощью jquery. Но мой код смены класса почему-то не работает. Код, который у меня есть в jquery, отлично работает с другими ссылками, но не работает с navbar. В чем проблема?

Код моего меню:

```
<header class="d-flex main-header">
    <div class="container header-container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse main-navigation fixed-top">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center content-nav-wrapper col-10 offset-1">
                <h1 class="mr-auto"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/site_logo.png" alt="logo"></a></h1>
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right offcanvas-toggle menu-button align-self-center" type="button"
                        data-toggle="offcanvas"
                        data-target="#js-bootstrap-offcanvas" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-offcanvas navbar-offcanvas-touch navbar-offcanvas-right menu"
                     id="js-bootstrap-offcanvas">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-md-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#team">Team</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Код jquery для изменения активного класса, он отлично работает с другими меню, но вот именно с navbar не работает, не могу понять почему:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navbar .navbar-nav li a").click(function () {
        $(".navbar .navbar-nav li a").removeClass("active-nav-link");
        $(this).addClass("active-nav-link");
    });
});
```

Также у меня есть jquery для плавного перехода к секциям после нажатия и изменения активного класса в меню при прокрутке страницы пользователем к определённой секции, может проблема в нём:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    var $sections = $('section');
    $sections.each(function(i,el){
        var top  = $(el).offset().top-100;
        var bottom = top +$(el).height();
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        var id = $(el).attr('id');
        if( scroll > top && scroll < bottom){
            $('a.active-section-link').removeClass('active-section-link');
            $('a[href="#'+id+'"]').addClass('active-section-link');

        }
    })
});

$("nav").on("click","a", function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
        top = $(id).offset().top;
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 800);
});
```

Мой Sass для меню:

```
.main-header {

  .header-container {
    width: inherit;
  }

  .menu {
    overflow: hidden;

    .nav-link {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 1.2rem;

        &:hover {
          color: #2ecc71;
        }
    }
  }

@media (min-width: 768px) { 
.menu {

      .active-section-link {
        color: #2ecc71;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        border-radius: 10px;
      }

      .active-nav-link {
        color: #2ecc71;
      }
    }
}
```